# C# WPF Insert a textBox inside a Menu Stretched Out

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to insert a TextBox (with its corresponding greyed out value) inside a menu.

I've tried many things (below my latest attempt)

1. Either the textBox isn't stretched along all the menu
2. The Menu has some weird offset

I've tried putting it inside a grid but it adds a weird offset on the right

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6OtX.png)

```
<Window x:Class="NotepadMain.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NotepadMain"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="FirePad - A Notepad for the 21st Century" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                  FontFamily="Consolas"
                  FontSize="20">
                <MenuItem Header="_File" Width="auto">
                    <MenuItem Header="New" x:Name="newMenus" >
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Assets/new.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Save" x:Name="saveMenus" Click="saveMenus_Click" >
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Assets/save.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="SaveAs" x:Name="saveAsMenus" Click="saveAsMenus_Click" >
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Assets/save_as.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Open" x:Name="openMenus" Click="openMenus_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Assets/open.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="Print">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Assets/print.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem Header="Edit">
                    <MenuItem Header="Copy" x:Name="copyMenus" >
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Assets/copy.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Paste" x:Name="pasteMenus" >
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Assets/paste.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Cut" x:Name="cutMenus" >
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Assets/cut.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Undo" x:Name="undoMenus" >
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Assets/undo.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Redo" x:Name="redoMenus" >
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Assets/redo.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator/>

                    <TextBox  TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100" Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBox.ToolTip>Highlight a Word in the Text</TextBox.ToolTip>
                    </TextBox>

                </MenuItem>
                
            </Menu>
        </DockPanel>
        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="richTextBox1">
            
        </RichTextBox>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code above is my latest attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the MenuItem has an offset that is causing you to see the blue-ish highlight on the left and right of the TextBox.

You need to override the ControlTemplate of a MenuItem if you want that area to be more flushed to the edge of its container.  Search for "wpf menuitem controltemplate" and go to Microsoft's page that shows an example.

In their example, you will see something like this snippet:

```cs
<!-- SubmenuItem -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}"
                 TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
  <Border x:Name="Border"
          BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                          SharedSizeGroup="Icon" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                          SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                        Margin="6,0,6,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        ContentSource="Icon" />
```

Modify the last `ColumnDefinition`'s width and you will see its effect on your result. From here on out, you can play around with the Grid ColumnDefinitions the way you want. *Note: This will affect all of your menu items, so be aware of that.*